# CCFollow does not stopping following

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, set, screen, center

Hi this is my first question in cocos2d!
I am using this code to follow the ball :

```
 [self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:ball]];
```

i need a code the action will be stopped before we can see a black background...

Sorry for the bad english!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the world boundary of the follow, which will constrain the follow to the defined rect:

```
[self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:ball worldBoundary:CGRectMake(0,0,WINWIDTH,WINHEIGHT)]];
```